# DB2 Error while proccesing UNIONALL between two queries

Tags: db2

I'm getting the following error while proccessing `union all` between two queries. Any suggestion of what might be the cause? I searched by the error code but don't know which error code is the cause and what might be the fix.

> "
>   An error occurred while processing the results. - [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.16.53] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
>   or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: Read timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
>   [jcc][10120][10943][4.16.53] Invalid operation: statement is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
>   "

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `union all` instead of `unionall`? And please show the query.

Comment: Do you have the JDBC driver property `blockingReadConnectionTimeout` set to something other than 0, by chance?